# MP critical point has morse index 1, proof

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, differential-topology

I wonder where can I find a proof of the following fact: **if the mountain pass critical point is non-degenerate, then its Morse index is 1**. I am very interested in reading it.
In general, I am interested in reading notes on Morse index and MP critical points. So I will be very grateful, if someone can suggest me some notes about that.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Please, check the book of Mawhin and Willem:   J. Mawhin,  M. Willem,  Critical Point Theory and Hamiltonian Systems,Vol. 74 of Applied Mathematical Sciences, Springer–Verlag, 1989 (1989).[

Answer (score 2):

I think you should have a looks at this paper "Variational and Topological Methods in Partially Ordered Hilbert Spaces" by Helmut Hofer in Mathematische Annalen 1982.